# Get Contents of a UserControl inside a StackPanel

Tags: wpf, user-controls, stackpanel

I have a `StackPanel` inside a WPF page, and I am loading the same UserControl inside it depending on the user requests.  Now for each of these UserControls, I need to get the items which are inside it.  The UserControl consists of a Calendar, and 3 comboboxes.  How can I get the items?

So far I have the following:-

```
foreach (UserControl child in stk.Children)
{

}
```

and child has the contents required, however I cannot find out how to get the contents of every child to validate and store in the database.  I tried child.FindControl("combobox1") but that did not work.

Thanks for your help and time

Comment: Where are you calling child.FindControl("combobox1") from? Is you child loaded when you call it?

Comment: The child has the data, so do I need to load the user control? Like UCPageControl ucPControl = new UCPageControl?  And then move the data in the child to this ucPControl?

Comment: No you don't have to, but child.FindControl("combobox1") can return null, if you call it before the parent control gets fully loaded. that's why i asked you where do you call it? Are you getting an exception or code just doesn't work?

Comment: Hi Dmitry, my child has only the following properties :-FindCommonVisualAncestor, FindName, FindResource, TryFindResource.  It does not have FindControl

Comment: I have found the following thread which was very helpful!  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/636383/wpf-ways-to-find-controls.....Thanks for all your help guys

Answer (score 0):

You can get hold of the `Content` . However I strongly suggest you don't do those of kind of things in the UI, and you shouldn't get the data from the UI. the UI should get the data from a ViewModel or a Model, and update them when needed(This is achieved through Binding). so if you need the data, your ViewModel should be the place to look at, not the UI.

Comment: Hi Mben I am not using the MVVM pattern yet, doing some basic stuff.  So lets say I load the control in the Page, how can I get the data from the Model?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the following thread which was very helpful!

[How can I find WPF controls by name or type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/636383/wpf-ways-to-find-controls)

It uses a helper to find all the controls in a WPF page.

Thanks for all your help guys